# How do I using android, programmatically send a vibrate command to a connected bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, vibration

I'm trying to achieve this goal: I have a bluetooth device connected to my android phone. Given this device can vibrate, is it possible to send a vibrate command to the device?

I have researched the bluetooth apis and the vibrate api on android developers' site but nothing clearly answers my question.

Comment: What devices are we talking about? Model numbers? Likely you can't unless you know the specifications of the client device. AFAIK there isn't anything like this in the specification.

Comment: @Mgamerz I'm referring to a Bluetooth enabled bracelet. It could be any device though. But for my specific ex. I picked a bracelet that I want to vibrate for any event on my device. [link] (http://www.amazon.com/Koolertron-Bluetooth-Bracelet-Cellphone-Incoming/dp/B0058LOZMA )

Answer (score 2):

In bluetooth HFP (Handsfree) spec, there is no command (AT Command) to send vibrate to the peer device. As per the technical specification of bracelet "Vibration prompt for incoming phone" , once an AT command is send from phone to bracelet indicating a incoming call, bracelet generates vibration locally, phone does not ask/request to vibrate.

If you want peer device to vibrate,may be you have to use your own defined commands (AT command), with command recognized by the peer device.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I will give it a try and update this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very glad to update this thread that I was able to programmatically vibrate the BT bracelet and in the right way using AT commands. So my application is based on Bluetooth Chat application in the Android samples. Here are the steps I followed:

1. connect the device to the phone
2. device follows BT Hands-Free profile specification. That requires "handshaking" by means of AT commands.
   So I mimic this exchange of commands (with hard coded responses to bracelet's commands)
3. Once handshake is complete, I send AT command based on BT Hands-Free profile specification to RING  and +CLIP:
4. On receiving the last set of response from application, the bracelet vibrates.

It seems simple, but without knowledge of BT Hands-Free profile specification, and sample AT commands this was nearly impossible.

@bt_user: Thanks for your pointer, that put me on the right track of R&D.

Comment: I am also working on connecting to Bluetooth Bracelet. I was able to use the AT command to make it vibrate. Can you tell me what is the AT command to send text to the BT bracelet Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't happen to share this on github by chance?  I'm try to do the same thing for my wife.

Comment: Please share your Code on Github or something else, I think there are more use cases for those bracelets

Answer (score 1):

I was fiddeling with exaclty the same problem. After days of trial and error, I finally got it to work. I think it depends on the speed at wich you answer the HF's commands, as well as on the correct line-endings ([13][10]"COMMAND"[13][10]).

Here is my DroidScript which works. It's not cleaned up, but it works.

https://gist.github.com/t-oster/68a568ac4c4e133f67ac

The exact sequence, which works for my bracelet is:

CR is ASCII Code 13 and LF is ASCII Code 10

```
> AT+BRSF=0<cr>
< <cr><lf>+BRSF:0<cr><lf>
< <cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>
> AT+CIND=?<cr>
< <cr><lf>+CIND: ("service",(0,1)),("call",(0,1))<cr><lf>
< <cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>
> AT+CIND?<cr>
< <cr><lf>+CIND: 1,0<cr><lf>
< <cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>
> AT+CMER=3,0,0,1<cr>
> <cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>
```

from then on I can just send

```
<cr><lf>RING<cr><lf>
```

to make it vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

i have developed a java android version
using parts from Thomas Oster and an example i found online

https://gist.github.com/shimondoodkin/a582d910045ab06ab68c